# AWS EC2 IAM Role Credentials not passed into Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am developing a Node.js application which is deployed on an EC2 instance. I am using the AWS SDK for JavaScript. I have tried both v2 and v3. My problem is that whenever I make a call to any AWS service in my application, I get an error saying that the credentials are missing. However, according to the documentation, assigning an IAM role to the EC2 instance should enable the SDK to automatically retrieve the credentials: [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-iam.html). I believe that I have correctly added the IAM role with sufficient permissions to the EC2 instance so I don't understand why the requests are not going through. I do not want to use Environment variables as I would have to manually use them in my code then. Any suggestions of how to debug this issue or thoughts what the problem might be, are greatly appreciated.

For example, a call is made as follows:

```
const client = new CloudFormationClient({ region: "eu-central-1" });
const params = {
    StackStatusFilter: [
        "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS"
    ]
};

const command = new ListStacksCommand(params);
client.send(command).then(
    (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

The error is simply: Error: Credential is missing.
This originates from the console.log(error).

In have tried with multiple roles but even with the AdministratorAccess the same error occurs. For reference, the permissions are:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the call you are making and the error you get?

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. Can you show the policies attached to the IAM Role?

Comment: Can you run any aws cli commands on the same ec2 instance to check if those work?